# Error page on SSL negotiation failure

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

We're updating our nginx config to remove some older/less secure cypher suites.

For the overwhelming majority of cases this shouldn't cause any issues, however, older versions of Windows (and very early versions of Windows 10) will not be able to negotiate a connection as there will be no cipher suites in common.

We're taking a "secure by default" approach but will allow users to downgrade the security of their deployment if the change causes them issues.

My question is ...

Can I get nginx to redirect to an error page if SSL negotiation fails?

[presumably over HTTP, although I could live with running a different, insecure, server/config to serve a single error file]

I note CloudFlare have adopted HTTP 525 to indicate "SSL negotiation failed" but in their case, they're 2-hop and are thus reporting their own failure to connect downstream, rather than handling a failure to connect to cloudflare itself, so I can't see any easy way to leverage this (plus it's non-standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no.

Redirection is an HTTP thing. This happens after SSL/TLS negoatiation has complete succesfully.

If you include an insecure cyphers in ssl_ciphers (make sure you set this up so the strong ones are preferred - i.e. first in the list) then your old clients will still be able to connect and your webserver will be able to talk to them. From that point it *may* be possible to define a different behaviour based on [$ssl_cypher](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_cipher)

Something long the lines of (NB not tested)

```
if ($ssl_cipher = "DES-CBC3-SHA" ) {
    rewrite  (.*)  https://insecure.com$1;
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I like the way you've inverted the problem to find a solution, but that would look like we do accept those connections to the outside world, meaning we'd fail automated tests/fuzzing attacks, probably sinking a lot of time into explaining how it is secure _really_. I'm also not a huge fan of relying on explicitly checking for bad cyphers. It seems error-prone (although I suppose I could invert the conditional as well and do `$ssl_cipher != ...` which is marginally more robust). I'll leave this open a little while in the hope of better alternatives, thanks.

Comment: " I could invert the conditional" - no because you only need one weak cypher but you should have at least 3 good ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I need 2 weak ones for two different cases, but I'd prefer a whitelist over a blacklist... As I can't do an `OR` or an `IN(..., ...)`, it might have to be a series of `IF`s setting a variable to test later, or similar.

Comment: Still - the past is better defined than the future - hence detecting the known "bad" cases minimises the config / reconfig.

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to have to agree to disagree... Secure by default, not secure by optimism IMO.

Comment: One can use nginx `map` feature to do multiple conditions.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thank you, I wasn't aware of that.